# MVC5 Post data from partial view being used in main view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have already tried many solutions available on web as per my understanding in context to this question but being new in MVC I am still unable to find a solution. Kindly help.

I have a view which is the home page of the website named as **"Index.cshtml"** and is situated under the following path:
**WebsiteName/Areas/Website/Views/CypressHome/Index.cshtml**

Secondly, I have a created a user trial form as partial view named as **"_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial.cshtml"** which is situated under the following path:
**WebsiteName/Areas/Website/Shared/_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial.cshtml**.
This form I have used inside my "Index.cshtml" as below:

```
<!--freetrialform-->
    @Html.Partial("_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial")
<!--//freetrialform-->
```

Now, my partial page is posting data comprising of following elements:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input__field input__field--kuro" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    ............
    other fields such as email, phone, date, etc..
    <input type="submit" id="" value="SEND REQUEST" />
    </div>
}
```

Now, I have created a controller named "CustomerController" which has the following code to save the data of the form as **used as partial view** in the **main view "Index.cshtml"**:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private WebsiteContext db = new WebsiteContext();

    // GET: Website/Customer
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Website/Customer/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.StatusPlanID = new SelectList(db.StatusPlans, "StatusPlanID", "Status");
        return View("Index");
    }

    // POST: Website/Customer/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerEmail,CustomerPhone,DateOfRegistration,StatusPlanID")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.StatusPlanID = new SelectList(db.StatusPlans, "StatusPlanID", "Status", customer.StatusPlanID);
        return View(customer);
    }
}
```

> I have tried many changes in my controller, return in the views and
>   many other things but I am getting the same error always. Neither the
>   validations are working nor the validated data is getting saved.

**The error is as below:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/Website/Views/Customer/Create.aspx
~/Areas/Website/Views/Customer/Create.ascx
~/Areas/Website/Views/Shared/Create.aspx
~/Areas/Website/Views/Shared/Create.ascx
~/Views/Customer/Create.aspx
~/Views/Customer/Create.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Create.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Create.ascx
~/Areas/Website/Views/Customer/Create.cshtml
~/Areas/Website/Views/Customer/Create.vbhtml
~/Areas/Website/Views/Shared/Create.cshtml
~/Areas/Website/Views/Shared/Create.vbhtml
~/Views/Customer/Create.cshtml
~/Views/Customer/Create.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Create.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Create.vbhtml
```

> And the url is changing as below:
>   1. On running the system initially: http://localhost:53872/
>   2. On clicking on submit: http://localhost:53872/Areas/Website/Customer/Create along with the
>   error as stated above.

For more information my WebsiteAreaRegistration.cs file contains the below code:

```
public class WebsiteAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Website";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Website_home",
            "",
            new { controller = "CypressHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Website_default",
            "Areas/Website/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "CypressHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Though I have understood the problem but unable to figure out. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code last return statement is  `return View(customer)`. That's means after **POST** data it return a View (using HTTP GET method) as same name as **Action** that's **Create**. But your description you have a **Create Action** but you have no view page.
So please create a `Create.cshtml` with a Model corresponding **customer Object**.
Or change the return statement.

**Based on your comment you can follow this Change.**

1.Remove

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.StatusPlanID = new SelectList(db.StatusPlans, "StatusPlanID", "Status");
        return View("Index");
    }
```

2.then change

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {

      ViewBag.StatusPlanID = new SelectList(db.StatusPlans, "StatusPlanID", "Status");

      return View(new Customer());
  }
```

3.in `Index.cshtml`

```
@Model Customer        
@Html.Partial("_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial",Model)
```

4.Then

```
   return View("Index",customer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shall I change the name of my partial page to create.cshtml? Or if you can help me what should I write in return statement as I have already tried this return View("~/Areas/Website/CypressHome/Index");

Comment: No you must use view.you can use 'return PartialView()' but  If you use return PartialView() then you loss your design. you can use  return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: Can you please write your Customer Object Class name?

Comment: I followed the steps as you have stated above but again the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but unfortunately this also doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you so much but some part of your answer actually worked for me. I finally moved page _PartialHomeFormFreeTrial.cshtml from Shared to Folder inside view named "CypressHome". Then in my controller I changed function name "Create()" to "_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial()". Then lastly in the view _PartialHomeFormFreeTrial.cshtml, I updated to the following line: @using (Html.BeginForm("_PartialHomeFormFreeTrial", "CypressHome", FormMethod.Post)). As per your suggestions this helped me: return View("Index", customer);

Comment: Anything better than this if can be achieved please suggest. As what I did is actually not a good solution.

Comment: Please read any document about razor. How to partial page work and How to work Html.BeginForm http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/2171/partial-views#t=201704200944432342235

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142275/discussion-between-ashiquzzaman-and-karishma).